# Can Air planes fly through rainbows?

Tags: commercial-aviation, general-aviation

I am wondering whether or not it is possible for an air plane to fly through a rainbow, and, if so, does anyone have any pictures or experiences of what you can see?

I've always been intrigued by this.

Comment: Why cant fly though rainbow?

Comment: This question belongs on SE.Physics but the short answer is no.  A rainbow does not exist.  It's an illusion caused by refraction of light rays.  The observer must always be between the light source and the rainbow.  Imagine the conditions are right for the rainbow to exist for ever.  You would also travel for ever trying to reach it.  Incidentally, all rainbows are circular.  It's just that most of the ones we see are interrupted by the ground. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow

Comment: Better posed on earthscience.se or physics.se , but ^^^ is the answer.

Comment: @Simon: So you say there is no pod of gold where  the rainbow touches the ground? :-( Seriously: That myth exists because you can not prove it, as you can never reach that point:  It just does not exist. For the same reason, an aircraft will never fly though a rainbow, even if it seems so for an observer on the ground.

Comment: I have a side question making this question more aviation-related: On ground, a rainbow is a half circle, well, because there is ground. For a flying observer, a rainbow could form a full circle. Has anybody ever seen this effect?

Comment: @sweber Yes.  I've seen one.  The point about an observer is strictly incorrect since no 2 people can see the same rainbow.

Comment: @sweber Yes.  Search images for "full circle rainbow plane" and you'll find many such examples.

Comment: Flying inside a rainbow is not recommended as it can [destroy the aircraft external skin](http://airportjournals.com/wp-content/uploads/0603017_2.jpg).

Comment: Possibly one of the best questions I've seen on this forum.  Also, can Air planes fly faster than unicorns?

Comment: On first reading the title I thought it was about a new Canadian airline.

Comment: Of course they can a rainbow is reflecting light from the sun anything could go through a rainbow

Comment: @mins I love this comment!

Comment: Unicorns can. When they do it creates a pot-o-gold at one end. This P.O.G. attracts Leprechauns. When the Leprechauns get that POG the rainbow disappears. Then the Leprechauns go to the nearest pub (after changing their clothes so as to not attract attention) and spend that POG. When the POG is empty the Leprechauns stagger out of the pub and barf. This post-pub-crawl ritual creates a rainbow which attracts unicorns ...  That the pub crawl happens at night explains why we never see unicorns.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by fly through. I flew under a rainbow once. I was flying a tactical jet over the Mediterranean when I saw a full rainbow from horizon-to-horizon in the distance. Thought about it for a second, and realized I will never get this chance again, and so off I went. As I approached it I watched the ends come together from the horizons. By the time I got under the rainbow it was a full ring around the A7E. Did an aileron roll to check it out. Very cool experience. Always thought that the Leprechauns were very clever to hide their gold at the end of the rainbow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A rainbow is created by refraction of sunlight so you have to be in the right position to see it. The effect is only created at some distance. A rainbow that you see from the ground may appear to be in a particular place in the sky. An airplane could fly through that space and it might appear to *you* that it is passing through it The occupants of the airplane, however, would not see a rainbow there.

Comment: The physics forum might yield a better answer since this is really a question about optics. Besides, I was working hard not to be funny and say they would crash into 'em.

Answer (score 5):

Running into a rainbow is hard, whether walking, driving, or flying.  The reason is that rainbows are not objects - they are an optical illusion that only exists in the eye of the observer.

Trying walking toward a rainbow.  You'll find it moves away, and eventually disappears.  This is one reason why you'll hear people say there's a pot of gold at the end of the rainbow to describe wishful thinking.  You can never get to with end of the rainbow - the more you move, the more it moves.

Being an optical illusion, it has absolutely no impact on other physical objects.  So if you are on the ground, you could observe an airplane flying through a rainbow that you see.  The pilots on the flight would not see the same rainbow you see, and would not be able to tell that they are flying through the optical illusion you are experiencing. They would, however, encounter the water that is creating the illusion for you.  Fortunately most planes have no problem flying through mist or rain, and thus there is no problem.

The reason you rarely see photos of planes flying through rainbows is that few pilots enjoy flying through the weather that creates these illusions, and try to avoid them by flying over or around the situation that would create a rainbow.

Comment: I once saw a rainbow that terminated over Centre 1, East Kilbride, famous in the UK as the headquarters of Inland Revenue. Yes, I did get quite a nice income tax rebate that year.

Comment: From the air, rainbows are circular!  Not just merely the arch you see from the ground. We've seen some nice ones flying in a small plane at lower altitudes.